# Скажите что не так прогой, почему Y должна быть -7, а по факту выходит что она 1

Tags: python

```
Условие
```

Шахматный король ходит по горизонтали, вертикали и диагонали, но только на 1 клетку. Даны две различные клетки шахматной доски, определите, может ли король попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом. Программа получает на вход четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое, задающие номер столбца и номер строки сначала для первой клетки, потом для второй клетки. Программа должна вывести YES, если из первой клетки ходом короля можно попасть во вторую или NO в противном случае.
Ну а если прога совсем неправильная подскажите какая будет верной.

```
x = int(input()) #1
y = int(input()) #1
x2 = int(input()) #1
y2 = int(input()) #8

X = x - x2
Y = y - y2

if (X == 1 or -1 or 0) and (Y == 1 or -1 or 0):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Что делает `X == 1 or -1 or 0` ?

Comment: Проверяет равен ли X  1, -1 или 0

Comment: А вы проверяли что он именно это "проверяет"?

Comment: а что еще он может проверять?

Comment: `bool(2 == 1 or -1 or 0)` -> `True`.

Comment: Замените X == 1 or -1 or 0 на X == 1 or X == -1 or X == 0

Comment: спасибо, теперь буду знать как строить такие проверки

Answer (score 4):

У вас было не правильно записано условие

```
x = int(input()) #1
y = int(input()) #1
x2 = int(input()) #1
y2 = int(input()) #8

X = x - x2
Y = y - y2

if X in (1, -1, 0) and Y in (1, -1, 0):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Answer (score 3):

можно слегка упростить код таким образом:

```
x = abs(x - x2)
y = abs(y - y2)

print("YES" if x<2 and y<2 else 'NO')
```

Comment: а для чего здесь abs?

Comment: @Sargon, без `abs` условие `x<2 and y<2` не будет работать как надо, так-как для  любых отрицательных x и y оно будет истинным